# Using get method on form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that I just want to test if my input values are getting submitted correctly. I don't have any serve script setup yet but I thought I might be able to see my values been appended to my url when I click submit.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<form id="appointments" action="" method="get">
    <input  type="checkbox" name="check1" value="my value"/>
</form>
```

I have a div with a graphic on it which is been used for the submit and this is the code I'm using.

```
submit.click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $this.submit();
});
```

`this` is referring to the form id (`id="appointments"`).

When I submit nothing gets appended to my url. Anyone know why.

Comment: where is submit button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your declaration is wrong because normal javascript variable can be started with `$`, so `$this` is just a local variable, unless you use `$this = $(this)`

so instead of using `$this` use `$(this)` or `this.something`

Comment: I assume you mean a javascript variable *cannot* be defined by `$` which is wrong.  If you read the jQuery docs they use it a lot in plugins.

Comment: if he did $this = $(this) it would be fine.but he didn't

Comment: @Endophage i mean that `$this` is just a variable not a specific jquery Object

Comment: @diEcho you really need to rephrase that then because the first line really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
$("#yoursubmitbutton").click(function(evt){
      evt.preventDefault();
      $("#appointments").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$this = $(this);
```

also its not clear from the code to which elements you are attaching the click handler but you can try

```
$("form#appointments").submit();
```